# Response.Redirect not working when button on mastepage is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a button on the masterpage to logout when I click it it's supposed to close session and redirect to Login.

Login is the start page and it's not within the mastepage, it's just a sigle aspx page.

I have no idea why it's not working. I put a breakpoint in the button method but when I click the button the event is not fired.

The Button is **Salir**

Please help me out.

this is the code fo the masterpage:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Principal.master.cs" Inherits="Web.Principal" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="zxx" class="no-js">
        <head>
            <!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <!-- Favicon-->
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/fav.png">
            <!-- Author Meta -->
            <meta name="author" content="Colorlib">
            <!-- Meta Description -->
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <!-- Meta Keyword -->
            <meta name="keywords" content="">
            <!-- meta character set -->
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <!-- Site Title -->
            <title>Destinos Naturales S.A</title>

            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,400,300,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
                <!--

            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <!-- Start Header Area -->
                <header class="default-header">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="header-wrap">
                            <div class="header-top d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="logo">
                                    <a href="Principal.aspx"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="main-menubar d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <nav class="hide">
                                        <a href="Principal.aspx">
                                            <asp:Button ID="bntInicio" runat="server" Text="Inicio" BorderWidth="0" BackColor="Transparent"/>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="Usuario.aspx">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnUsuarios" runat="server" Text="Usuarios" BorderWidth="0" BackColor="Transparent"/>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="Articulos.aspx">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnArticulos" runat="server" Text="Artículos" BorderWidth="0" BackColor="Transparent"/>
                                        </a>
                                        <a>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnSalir" runat="server" Text="Salir" ForeColor="#800000" BorderWidth="0" BackColor="Transparent" OnClick="btnSalir_Click"/>
                                        </a>
                                    </nav>
                                    <div class="menu-bar"><span class="lnr lnr-menu"></span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <!-- End Header Area -->
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        </form>
<!-- start footer Area -->
            <footer class="footer-area section-gap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="single-footer-widget">
                                <h6>Destinos Naturales S.A</h6>
                                <p>
                                    Destinos turísticos nacionales e internacionales.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="single-footer-widget mail-chimp">
                                <h6 class="mb-20">Instragram</h6>
                                <ul class="instafeed d-flex flex-wrap">
                                    <li><img src="img/i1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                    <li><img src="img/i2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                    <li><img src="img/i3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                    <li><img src="img/i4.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                    <li><img src="img/i5.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                    <li><img src="img/i6.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                    <li><img src="img/i7.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                    <li><img src="img/i8.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="single-footer-widget">
                                <h6>¡Síguenos!</h6>
                                <p></p>
                                <div class="footer-social d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-bottom d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-wrap">
                        <p class="footer-text m-0">
                        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
                        Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | Hecho por Alejandra Porras Araya</a>
                        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            <!-- End footer Area -->
        </body>
    </html>
```

and This is button  code:

```
protected void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["UsuarioIngresado"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: You don't have any markup that ties the button to the click handler. Are you assigning it in code?

Comment: What do you mean? this?    **OnClick="btnSalir_Click"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invalid html comment in your code. `<!--` is the reason not  triggering `btnSalir_Click` event.

Removing `<!--` should fix the issue.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,400,300,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--
      ^^^^^
```

Comment: You're right I did not notice this. Thanks, this was the problem.